# Arrays sent in PHP like others vars (for each index)

Tags: php

I have seen some strange behavior in PHP, and I would like to know about this:

I am checking a project in PHP and have 2 file, so:

I have a form (Form.php) that send a file input named **fileUser** and the second file (receiver.php) retriveve the file input so:

```
<?php
  $size=$fileUser_size;
?>
```

I can see that PHP creates a variable named with the same name in the form **fileUser** and appends each index so:

```
$pruebafile_size  
$pruebafile_name
```

and so...

Anyone know about this behavior in PHP?

Note: The project is in PHP, register globals ON, and uses XAJAX.

Thanks.

Comment: sure there isn't an included script above that does create variables of some globals like you descibe?

Comment: or maybe an auto_prepended file? http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file